# Caching in AWS API Gateway new panel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

There was a recent change to AWS UI and now the cache settings in API Gateway seem missing. The instructions that are in the documentation [1] are leading nowhere. Am I missing something or is the page missing something?

I'm trying to set up caching for one stage of API Gateway proxy.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html

Answer (score 0):

Please double check. The cache settings are where they've always been - in **Stage settings**:

[image]

Comment: It seems you still have the classic UI here. Did you see this one? https://ibb.co/5c2KggG

Comment: @wiktus239 Not yet. Maybe have to enable new UI somewhere. I will check.